# Calling a class function inside of __init__

Tags: python, class

I'm writing some code that takes a filename, opens the file, and parses out some data. I'd like to do this in a class. The following code works:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename 

        self.stat1 = None
        self.stat2 = None
        self.stat3 = None
        self.stat4 = None
        self.stat5 = None

        def parse_file():
            #do some parsing
            self.stat1 = result_from_parse1
            self.stat2 = result_from_parse2
            self.stat3 = result_from_parse3
            self.stat4 = result_from_parse4
            self.stat5 = result_from_parse5

        parse_file()
```

But it involves me putting all of the parsing machinery in the scope of the `__init__` function for my class. That looks fine now for this simplified code, but the function `parse_file` has quite a few levels of indention as well. I'd prefer to define the function `parse_file()` as a class function like below:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename 

        self.stat1 = None
        self.stat2 = None
        self.stat3 = None
        self.stat4 = None
        self.stat5 = None
        parse_file()

    def parse_file():
        #do some parsing
        self.stat1 = result_from_parse1
        self.stat2 = result_from_parse2
        self.stat3 = result_from_parse3
        self.stat4 = result_from_parse4
        self.stat5 = result_from_parse5
```

Of course this code doesn't work because the function `parse_file()` is not within the scope of the `__init__` function. Is there a way to call a class function from within `__init__` of that class? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Is there any reason the code example needs five versions of "stat"?
It would make it easier to read if there would be only one.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Call the function in this way:

```
self.parse_file()
```

You also need to define your `parse_file()` function like this:

```
def parse_file(self):
```

The `parse_file` method has to be bound to an object upon calling it (because it's not a static method). This is done by calling the function on an instance of the object, in your case the instance is `self`.

Answer (score 60):

If I'm not wrong, both functions are part of your class, you should use it like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename 

        self.stat1 = None
        self.stat2 = None
        self.stat3 = None
        self.stat4 = None
        self.stat5 = None
        self.parse_file()

    def parse_file(self):
        #do some parsing
        self.stat1 = result_from_parse1
        self.stat2 = result_from_parse2
        self.stat3 = result_from_parse3
        self.stat4 = result_from_parse4
        self.stat5 = result_from_parse5
```

replace your line:

```
parse_file()
```

with:

```
self.parse_file()
```

Comment: Could you explain why it must be used `self.parse_file()` and not `parse_file()`?

Comment: @paritoshsingh should `def parse_file(self):` not be nested under the `__init__` function so that you don't have a partially initialised object?

Comment: @ivanleoncz As parse_file is instance method, we need to use reference object to call same.

Comment: @rong  If this code is venerable and you don't want to allow setting parse file from outside, yes it should be nested.

Comment: Consider using static methods https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod

Answer (score 18):

How about:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename 
        self.stats = parse_file(filename)

def parse_file(filename):
    #do some parsing
    return results_from_parse
```

By the way, if you have variables named `stat1`, `stat2`, etc., the situation is begging for a tuple:
`stats = (...)`.

So let `parse_file` return a tuple, and store the tuple in
`self.stats`.

Then, for example, you can access what used to be called `stat3` with `self.stats[2]`.

Comment: I agree, I just put the self.stat1 through self.stat5 in there to show that there were some class variables that I was assigning to. In the actual code I have a more elegant solution.

Comment: How should this be altered if I want to the `parse_file` function to be a method of the `MyClass` object. Where would `self` be necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You must declare parse_file like this; `def parse_file(self)`. The "self" parameter is a hidden parameter in most languages, but not in python. You must add it to the definition of all that methods that belong to a class.
Then you can call the function from any method inside the class using `self.parse_file`

your final program is going to look like this:

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, filename):
      self.filename = filename 

      self.stat1 = None
      self.stat2 = None
      self.stat3 = None
      self.stat4 = None
      self.stat5 = None
      self.parse_file()

  def parse_file(self):
      #do some parsing
      self.stat1 = result_from_parse1
      self.stat2 = result_from_parse2
      self.stat3 = result_from_parse3
      self.stat4 = result_from_parse4
      self.stat5 = result_from_parse5
```

Answer (score 0):

In `parse_file`, take the `self` argument (just like in `__init__`). If there's any other context you need then just pass it as additional arguments as usual.

Answer (score -15):

I think that your problem is actually with not correctly indenting **init** function.It should be like this

```
class MyClass():
     def __init__(self, filename):
          pass

     def parse_file():
          pass
```

Comment: Neither is your code. Unless you put the `@staticmethod` decorator on top of  `parse_file`

Comment: at least add the missing `self` in your `parse_file` method.

Comment: Oops, sorry there should have been an extra layer of indenting under the "class MyClass():" line. I've fixed it above, but the question remains the same.