# Python class database constructor

Tags: python, sql-server, class, syntax

I am trying to convert my script into a class, Since I will be using the connect method everytime, 
I want to place it in the constructor, and then call it in the other functions. 
I am new classes in Python, This is a

```
from datetime import date
import pymssql
import sys

class PHQuery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = self.conn()


    def get_stock_by_sku(self, sku):
        if self.conn["code"] < 0:
            return {"code":-1,"error":conn["error"]}
        cursor = self.conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
        try:
            cursor.execute('''
                SELECT NUMBER, UNITS, LOW, UNCOST, PRICE1, ONORDER 
                FROM STOCK 
                WHERE NUMBER=%s''', sku)
            return {"code":1,"data":cursor.fetchone()}
        except Exception as e:
            return {"code":-2,"error":e}

    def conn(self):
        try:
            conn = pymssql.connect(server='server', user='user', password='pwd', database='db', timeout=0, login_timeout=60, charset='UTF-8', as_dict=False, port='1433')
            return {"code":1,"data":conn}
        except Exception as e:
            return {"code":-1,"error":e}
```

OUTPUT ERRORS:

File "test.py", line 3, in 
    print testObject.get_stock_by_sku('BK31')
TypeError: unbound method get_stock_by_sku() must be called with PHQuery instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

THIS IS THE CALL TO THE METHOD

```
from query import PHQuery
testObject = PHQuery    
print testObject.get_stock_by_sku('BK31')
```

Here is my goal

```
data = {"stock_id" : "12345"}
qobject = PHQuery()
qobject.get_stock_by_sku(data["stock_id"])
```

and return the same data my script returns:
The script below is working perfectly fine, I just need to make it a class.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

WORKING CODE:

```
import time
from datetime import date
import pymssql
import sys

def conn():
    try:
        conn = pymssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='', timeout=0, login_timeout=60, charset='UTF-8', as_dict=False, port='1433')
        return {"code":1,"data":conn}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"code":-1,"error":e}
conn = conn()


def get_stock_by_sku(conn,sku):
    """ Returns stock information when passing a sku"""
    if conn["code"] < 0:
        return {"code":-1,"error":conn["error"]}
    cursor = conn["data"].cursor(as_dict=True)
    try:
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT NUMBER, UNITS, LOW, UNCOST, PRICE1, ONORDER 
            FROM STOCK 
            WHERE NUMBER=%s''', sku)
        return {"code":1,"data":cursor.fetchone()}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"code":-2,"error":e}
```

Comment: Why do you have this self.conn = self.conn ? should it be self.conn = self.conn() ? Also this seems wrong if self.conn.["code"] < 0: I think it should be if self.conn["code"] < 0: without the period

Comment: @altoids I had tried self.conn = self.conn() but I got: TypeError: conn() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: def conn(self): was the problem since I was calling the method in the constructor  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646326/calling-a-class-function-inside-of-init