# Why class methods called on other methods, should be called with 'self'?

Tags: python, oop, self

As I was reading this [tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm) about `tkinter` for my first steps with GUI in Python, I realized that a class function was called inside the `__init__` function.

I'd to like to understand, for what reason must be declared `self.class_function()` when calling a class function inside `__init__` function?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646326/calling-a-class-function-inside-of-init) question with this answer below, which just says that it must be called `self.class_function` and not `class_function`, without providing any concept or explanation about why it must be done like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename 

        self.stat1 = None
        self.stat2 = None
        self.stat3 = None
        self.stat4 = None
        self.stat5 = None
        self.parse_file()

    def parse_file(self):
        #do some parsing
        self.stat1 = result_from_parse1
        self.stat2 = result_from_parse2
        self.stat3 = result_from_parse3
        self.stat4 = result_from_parse4
        self.stat5 = result_from_parse5
```

Comment: You have to use self when calling class function. As it helps in identify how the function will behave for a particular object. It also helps during inheritance. Where you can change or override the base class function with another. Also the fact that on using static method. You have to provide all the instance information to the static function but what about the private class variable associated with object. How will you provide them to the static function that will be a dirty practice to follow.

Comment: Your example doesn't contain class methods. `parse_file` is an instance method.

Comment: If you want, you could also call it like `MyClass.parse_file(self)`

Comment: take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: Thanks, @AzatIbrakov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the reason you must call method with `self.method_name` instead of `method_name` is because, under the hood, Python substitutes the `self` portion to the first argument of the method.

You can test this for yourself by defining a class called Foo:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.fun()
  def fun(self):
    print("fun")
```

You can actually call the `fun()` method by performing the following:

```
foo = Foo()
Foo.fun(foo)
```

This will be the same as performing `self.fun()` from within the class.

Please note that you cannot access private fields statically (e.g `Foo._private_method(foo)`.)

Comment: Also the fact that info about private class variables can't be shared to static function.

Comment: @RajanChauhan huh? What do you mean? If you define a `_private_method` then sure you can. Python doesn't really have "private methods" anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was talking about class variable can't be shared with static function in a clean way. In order to do so you have to have their accessing functions. Yes in Python there is nothing truly private. But in true sense it will be a bad practice to follow. If you are the owner of your code. You have open boundaries no walls.

Answer (score 1):

> *for what reason must be declared self.class_function() when calling a class function inside `__init__` function?*

`self.foo()` refers to instance methods of the class and not static methods or another methods from other modules...

in that way you do something similar to this.foo() in other languages, in other words: `self.foo()` is meaning to call a foo method of that object!

Comment: "and not static methods" No - `staticmethod`s will be called, also, so will `classmethods`.